# How to use streamlit in ROS?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros, streamlit

I have a ROS node written in Python that captures messages and writes them to disk but I also need to visualize my data through a web interface. I am an experienced Streamlit user but I couldn't find an appropriate way to use this library in ROS. In Streamlit to run our code, there is command: "streamlit run FILENAME.py"

But in ROS, in order to subscribe from the ROS nodes, I need to run my python file using rosrun or roslaunch.

Any idea How to use these libraries together?
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example on how to use ROS subscribe and publish in combination with streamlit. In this example a String gets published to the rostopic `/mystring` when the input text field is changed. The streamlit metric is updated every second with the current Int32 value published to the rostopic `/mynumber`

Python Code:

```
from streamlit import cli as stcli
import streamlit as st
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int32
import sys
import time

mynum=0
mydelta=0

def callback(data):
  global mydelta, mynum
  mydelta=mynum-data.data
  mynum=data.data
  #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)

def getData():
  return mynum, mydelta

rospy.init_node('my_streamlit_ros_node')
pub = rospy.Publisher('/mystring', String, queue_size=10)
rospy.Subscriber("mynumber", Int32 , callback)


def main():
  st.title('Streamlit APP:')
  st.subheader('Commuicating with ROS')
  mytext = st.text_input('Send String to ROS', 'Life of Brian')
  pub.publish(mytext)
  metrics = st.empty()
  while True:
    mynum, mydelta=getData()
    with metrics:
      st.metric(label="Get Int32 Number from ROS", value=mynum, delta=mydelta, delta_color="inverse")
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if st._is_running_with_streamlit:
        main()
    else:
        sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", sys.argv[0]]
        sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

Execution:

1. source your ros workspace
2. python3 scriptname.py

Comment: `if st._is_running_with_streamlit` is not working anymore, do you know what is the latest update for this?